# What is the correct type I should use to store a date up to the minute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datetime, date, types

I want to store the date of an event in my database, but I want to do so without storing informations about seconds or anything smaller than seconds. Using Rails, in my migration I have the option to create a `date` column or a `datetime` column, the first one of which is too less accurate, and the second one is too much (up to the second and less). Which type should I choose to store such a date? Currently I'm using `datetime` and setting the seconds to a fixed value (e.g. 0) manually each time some date is set in the model.

Something like this:

```
self.date ||= Time.now.change(:sec => 0)
```

Am I totally out of track? Should I just use an integer field for each component of the date instead? (year, month, day, etc...) Or is `datetime` the correct type but I'm not understanding the purpose of it? (I think it's meant for timestamps and such things where seconds matter)

Comment: Yup, `datetime` is the correct type. Your only other option would be `varchar` or just a plain old `timestamp`/`int` column. But those all have other drawbacks compared to `datetime` and you will still need to manually drop the seconds off the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` is the correct type. And be sure to store it without time zone at time zone UTC:

http://derickrethans.nl/storing-date-time-in-database.html

At your option, use an SQL trigger to round your date to the minute on insert/update. It'll simplify your ruby code.